# Keep a service running in background in angular

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-services

I have created an API for analytics which relies on client sending it a request with a session ID (which is only kept in a var so that it resets every time the page is reloaded) every few minutes. I've created an angular service to send requests from the client but I can't get it to keep running and execute the function every few seconds.

I've imported the service in all the components and declared it in the constructor; and provided it only in app module so the same instance is available to all the components

all my components are spawned in my app component by router-outlet

Service:

```
declare var $:any;
export class AnalyticsService {
  sessionID = '';
  uniqueID = '';
  sendStatData() {
    const delay = (ms: number) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    const sendRequest = () => $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.com/aah',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        timeZone: Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone,
        sessionID: this.sessionID,
        uniqueID: this.uniqueID,
        address: '',
      })
    });
    const resp = sendRequest()
      .done(response => {
        if (response) {
          console.log(response);
          const data = response;
          if (data.sessionID !== undefined) {
            this.sessionID = data.sessionID;
          }
          if (data.uniqueID !== undefined) {
            localStorage.setItem('uniqueID', data.uniqueID);
            this.uniqueID = data.uniqueID;
          }
          if (data.message === 'uniqueID not found in database') {
            localStorage.removeItem('uniqueID');
            this.uniqueID = '';
            sendRequest();
          }
          delay(30000);
          sendRequest();
        }
      });
  }
  start() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('uniqueID') !== null){
      this.uniqueID = localStorage.getItem('uniqueID');
    }
    this.sendStatData();
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
.
.
import {AnalyticsService} from './analytics.service';
.
.
@NgModule({
  .
  .
  .
  providers: [AnalyticsService],
  .
  .
})
```

app.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AnalyticsService} from './analytics.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: AnalyticsService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.start();
  }
}
```

social.component.ts (others are the same in terms of service implementation) :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AnalyticsService} from '../analytics.service';
declare var $:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-skills',
  templateUrl: './skills.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./skills.component.css']
})
export class SkillsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: AnalyticsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Desired:

the service sends a request to my API every 30 seconds with the session ID which is stored

Actual:

the service only sends a request once when the site is reloaded regardless of the component being viewed

Comment: Hello, first why don't you use Angular HttpClient ? You will be able to combine RXJS timer and your service call. with something like that : `const timer$ = timer(0, 30000);
      this.cache$ = timer$.pipe(
        switchMap(_ => this.sendRequest()),
        shareReplay(1)
      );`

Answer (score 1):

As @Gilsdav has suggested, this should be switched to some kind of outside timing mechanism instead of delaying inside the response recursively. Also seconded on the opinion to make use of Angulars' built-in HttpClient instead of using jquery ajax calls (note: last I heard it's generally advised to not use jquery with Angular if you can avoid it).

At it's most basic, for anything repetitive, you can get away with something like this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

ngOnInit(): void {
  setInterval(() => { this.sendRequest(); }, 30000);
}

sendRequest(): void {
  this.http.post('https://api.com/aah', data)
    .subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
}
```

But you may well want to use something more integrated with what you have available (using rxjs, etc. as already suggested).